# Visually organizing classes in package

Tags: eclipse

I have a package with a lot of classes, and I want to organize them. I would happily split them into several packages based on my "category" of class, but unfortunately most of them are parts of a united system with package-level visibility.

Is there any way to create some sort of "subfolders" inside a package in Eclipse just to visually divide files in groups?

Answer (score 1):

Try to use working sets. This won't organize your classes, but help you to display just you need at a moment.